# Cover all columns using the least amount of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe looking like the following picture:

[image]

The goal here is to select the least amount of rows to have a "1" in all columns. In this scenario, the final selection should be these two rows:

[image]

The algorithm should work even if I add columns and rows. It should also work if I change the combination of 1 and 0 in any given row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, this is how I managed to do it:

```
def _getBestRowsFinalSelection(self, df, cols):
    """
        Get the selected rows for the final selection

            Parameters:
                 1. df: Dataframe to use
                 2. cols: Columns of the binary variables in the Dataframe object (df)

        RETURNS -> DataFrame : dfSelected
    """
    isOne = df.loc[df[df.loc[:, cols] == 1].sum(axis=1) > 0, :]
    lstIsOne = isOne.loc[:, cols].values.tolist()
    lstIsOne = [(x, lstItem) for x, lstItem in zip(isOne.index.values.tolist(), lstIsOne)]
    winningComb = None
    stopFlag = False

    for i in range(1, isOne.shape[0] + 1):
        if stopFlag:
            break;
        combs = combinations(lstIsOne, i) #from itertools

        for c in combs:
            data = [x[1] for x in c]
            index = [x[0] for x in c]
            dfTmp = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols, index=index)
            if (dfTmp.sum() > 0).all():
                dfTmp["Final Selection"] = "Yes"
                winningComb = dfTmp
                stopFlag = True
                break;


    return winningComb
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sum per rows, then compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) (`>=`) for greater or equal and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.sum(axis=1).ge(2)]
```

It want test `1` or `0` values first compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for equal `==`:

```
df[df.eq(1).sum(axis=1).ge(2)]
df[df.eq(0).sum(axis=1).ge(2)]
```

Comment: It worked, didn't know about the "ge" function. Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I tested it with another scenario and it doesn't work. Here's the scenario: https://imgur.com/x5ByYrg

Comment: @FanaticPythoner So need True if exactly 2 values? Then use `df[df.sum(axis=1).eq(2)]`